# Vim: Undo persistence stored in a shared folder of Linux guest VM and Windows Host

Tags: linux, windows, vim, persistence, undo-redo

**The problem**:
"Easy" set up of persistent undo with OS agnostic file naming relative to the home directory.

**Subproblem:** The command `:substitute(expand('%:p'), $HOME, "", "")` to get the path of a file relative to the home directory works in Vim on Linux (Fedora 22) but not on gVim (and Vim) on Windows (8.1). I've looked at the documentation and online and haven't found this issue elsewhere. The fact it works on one version and not another seems is a bit baffling.

**Context:** I've been trying to set up an undo folder for Vim, so that undo files are stored in one directory `$HOME\Programming\Vim\vimfiles` on Windows and `$HOME\.vim\undo` on Linux (symlinked to correct location).

I use the same vimrc across Vim on a Fedora 22 VM via VirtualBox (using a shared folder `$HOME/Programming` on both guest and host) and gVim on Windows. It takes a bit of effort but it works really well now.

**Code:** I am very new to Vimscript (first attempt) and have tried my best to follow documentation (wherever found). The code is based off of an autocmd and function based in `:h undo-persistence` with a few changes.

```
" File name based relative to home based on path, OS agnostic
func FileNameUndo()
  if (expand('%:p')==$MYVIMRC)
    let relToHomePath = 'vimrc'    " to resolve _vimrc and .vimrc conflict
  else
    let relToHomePath = substitute(expand('%:p'), $HOME, "", "")
  endif
  if has('unix')
    let undoFileName  = substitute(relToHomePath, '/', '-', "g")
  else
    let undoFileName  = substitute(relToHomePath, '\', '-', "g")
  endif
  return undoFileName
endfunc
" File path to store undo
func FilePathUndo()
  if has('unix')
    let undoDirPath = $HOME . '/.vim/undo'
  else
    let undoDirPath = $HOME .'\Programming\Vim\vimfiles\undo'
  endif
  return undoDirPath    
endfunc
" Read in undo file
func ReadUndo()
  let undoFilePath = expand(FilePathUndo() . FileNameUndo())
  if filereadable(undoFilePath)
    rundo undoFilePath
  endif
endfunc
" Write out undo file
func WriteUndo()
  let undoFilePath = FilePathUndo() 
  if !isdirectory(undoFilePath)
      call mkdir(undoFilePath)
  endif
  let undoFileLoc = expand(undoFilePath . FileNameUndo())
  wundo undoFileLoc
endfunc
" Autocommands for undo-persistence
au BufReadPost * call ReadUndo()
au BufWritePost * call WriteUndo()
```

Comment: It seems to me the easiest way to get an undo directory relative to your home directory, would just be to use the `'undodir'` option. What is wrong with that option for your use case?

Comment: Well depending on whether you save from Linux or Windows, the actual name of the file will be different. So I can set it up to point to the correct folder, but because the undo files are named with the absolute path, I can get C:\\Users....undofile and /usr/...undofile for the same file.